# Overriding css style?

Tags: css, styles, overriding

I look on Stack Overflow, and didn't find the solution, I know how to override style if style exists, just change its property. But now I have a strange style to override

Here is an example of what I have

First I have this one:

```
.slikezamenjanje img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height:150px;
    padding-right:7px;
}
```

Now I need to override that style with just this one:

```
#zoomTarget .slikezamenjanje img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

The problem is that first style appends second, but I don't want that, in this second style what I need is just one line, not to append from the first style?

Comment: That's one hell of a class name.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Instead of override you can add another class to the element and then you have an extra abilities.
for example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="style1 style2"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
//only style for the first stylesheet
.style1 {
   width: 100%;      
}
//only style for second stylesheet
.style2 {
   width: 50%;     
}
//override all
.style1.style2 { 
   width: 70%;
}
```

Comment: What i got with this one, nothing, in second style i need to override   max-height:150px;
    padding-right:7px; to NOTHING!

Comment: Now I understand you, Gorostas, check out my post.

Comment: Maby instead of override css try to add another class to the element and then with css.

Answer (score 18):

You just have to reset the values *you don't want* to their defaults. No need to get into a mess by using `!important`.

```
#zoomTarget .slikezamenjanje img {
    max-height: auto;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

#### Hatting

I think the key datum you are missing is that CSS comes with **default values**. If you want to override a value, set it back to its default, [which you can look up](http://nimbupani.com/safe-css-defaults.html).

For example, all CSS `height` and `width` attributes default to `auto`.

Comment: Still got this  max-width: 100%; probem?

Comment: You shouldn't need `!important`, since `#zoomTarget .slikezamenjanje img` is more specific than `.slikezamenjanje img`