# Is there anyway to fetch site specific element style out of CSS file?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

Is there anyway I can access site CSS file and "ask" it to return the CSS style of the H1 element, or P or any specific element? (without primitive text scraping).
update: Server side solution also applicable

Pseudo code :)

```
CSSContent = (get CSS file content from external site)
$H1font-family = getStyle(csscontent, h1, get-font-family)
$H1font-size = getStylet(csscontent, h1, get-font-size)
```

Comment: What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Do you just want to get the styles that have been applied to an element?

Comment: @charlietfl - returning a specific DOM element style per site address (what is the H2 style of domain.com. what is the font family of P element in domain2.com etc.

Comment: @JacobGray - yes. a specific list of elements.

Comment: Use a headless browser and get those values from the elements in the dom. Parsing a whole site's stylesheets will be a complicated process, let a browser do that for you

Comment: a css file doesn't have enough info to determine what styles a given element would have. there are other sheets, media queries, js-added styles (ala `$(tag).hide()`), different browsers support different css props, stylish may be running, and so on...

Comment: @dandavis - Hmm.. agree. lets say that I need the final outcome as parsed by a specific pre-defined browser (let's say Chrome-desktop client). probably charlietfl solution might work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to override whatever is in the CSS. There are 2 ways of doing this (at least). One is by adding an additional class to the HTML tag; this solution is well outlined in another SO answer [Overriding css style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302877/overriding-css-style)

The alternative is to add inline style and add `!important` at the end, however the first solution is superior.

There is also the option of using  e.g `document.getElementsByTagName("H1")` , which would identify all of a certain tag and then using that in a function to manipulate the style of that particular tag.

Hope this helps.

Comment: OP is trying to access remote sites...don't see how this answers question directly