# How to override CSSin Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm trying to create a Wordpress child theme, but I can't seem to get it to override styles in the parent theme.

**functions.php**

```
<?php

if ( ! function_exists( 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' ) ) {
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );

    function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    }
}

/**
 *    WP Enqueue Stylesheets
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'rev_cust_enqueue_stylesheets' ) ) {
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'rev_cust_enqueue_stylesheets' );

    function rev_cust_enqueue_stylesheets() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'rev-main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/layout/css/rev_main.css', array(), '', 'all' );
    }
}

?>
```

**rev_main.css**

```
#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li {
    margin-left: 40px;
    line-height: 1.375;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    font-size: 1px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
 }
```

Why isn't my style class not being picked?

Thank you all in advance.

**UPDATE**

1. I don't think the css file even gets picked up,
2. I have the child theme enabled.

Comment: add !important to eveything

Comment: Also try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302877/overriding-css-style

Comment: Thank you for the response, but ` !important` does nothing.

Comment: I don't think the css file even gets picked up

Comment: it could be a ton of things. Can you reproduce the problem for us?

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev well you don't have to guess if the file was picked up. Inspect the page and see if it was loaded. You can look in the network or sources tab in dev tools, and you can find it in the element inspector.

Comment: Make sure `/layout/css/rev_main.css` exists. Also try using your browser's developer tools to see if your CSS is not even being applied to the elements in question, or if it's just being overridden.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was at:

```
get_template_directory_uri()
```

in:

```
/**
 *    WP Enqueue Stylesheets
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'rev_cust_enqueue_stylesheets' ) ) {
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'rev_cust_enqueue_stylesheets' );

    function rev_cust_enqueue_stylesheets() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'rev-main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/layout/css/rev_main.css', array(), '', 'all' );
    }
}

?>
```

This points to the parent theme, instead of the child theme.

It should be `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` as follows:

```
function rev_cust_enqueue_stylesheets() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'rev-main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layout/css/rev_main.css', array(), '', 'all' );
}
```